# Distribution of Wages

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, reference-request

Is there any paper that looks at the distribution of wages? I'd like to see how many workers are in each percentile of labor income. I know that you could compute it using CPS or US tax data, but I suppose somebody must have done that before..

Comment: 1% of workers are in each percentile kinda by definition, no? :)

Comment: Well, I stated it completely (but consistently) the wrong way. I phrased the percentiles as labor income :/

Comment: Do you want to know total income earned (yearly) or do you want to know the distribution of earning power (like, distribution of hourly wages---or hours worked in combination with income)? Could you clarify?

Comment: The former is sufficient. However, I guess the latter is more informative, so more information always beats less information (also for future visitors of this question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the 2010 US Census, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Household_income_in_the_United_States#Distribution_of_Household_Income) has pretty much exactly what you seem to be looking for.

A sample graph:

[image]

though they of course also have tables and links to more data.

Or if you prefer raw data, the [IRS SOI](http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats---Individual-Statistical-Tables-by-Size-of-Adjusted-Gross-Income) is available for 1996-2012.

And of course there's [Piketty and Saez seminal paper on the subject](http://eml.berkeley.edu/~saez/pikettyqje.pdf) (See Table 5 for their data analogous to the included Wikipedia picture)

And of course there's the BLS which publishes these things regularly by [demographic](http://www.bls.gov/cps/earnings.htm#demographics), [hourly only](http://www.bls.gov/cps/earnings.htm#hourly), or [occupation/industry](http://www.bls.gov/cps/earnings.htm#occind).

Comment: It could be that the OP is looking for wages rather than income (like, hourly wages versus total yearly income earned).

Comment: could be, though would one not normally just divide by 2000 for US data?

Comment: No, because you don't know how many hours each individual worked (not average hours worked, I mean how many hours each individual worked). The question is important if you want to know something akin to the distribution of skill---or at least earning power---in the population.

Comment: that's problematic because high skill workers in the US are almost often (if not predominantly) salaried. Though you might be able to use the BLS data I just added for some of that.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Yeah, problematic to find/estimate the figures, but still important to know. (I'm thinking about Mirrlees optimal taxation again.)

Comment: @jmbejara http://www.bls.gov/news.release/wkyeng.t05.htm is as close as I think you could get, and you'd have to assume equiavlent weeks on average.